# Prove a Retraction of X Onto A is Continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $A$ $\subset$ $X$. A retraction of $X$ onto $A$ is a map $r$: $X \rightarrow A$ such that $r(a) = a$  $\forall$$a$ $\in$$A$. Prove that a retraction is a quotient map.

Usually, a retraction is defined as a continuous map. If a retraction is defined to be continuous, I know how to show this to be true. However, I do not know how to show this map is continuous. My initial thought was to consider an open set $U$ $\subset$ $A$. Then, $f^{-1}(U) = U$ $\subset$ $X$. Then Since $U$ is open in $A$, $\implies$ $U$ is open in $X$. However, this is not actually true in all cases.

Any help showing how this is continuous would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think that there is a convention at the begining,where the author assumes maps to mean continuous maps(as is usually done in algebraic topology books),coz continuity doesn't follow automotacilly from being the identity at $A$,in fact the statement is false for general  non continuous $r:X\mapsto A$ even if the restriction of $r$ tp $A$ is the identity

Comment: From what I understand and remember, retractions are continuous as part of their definition. In any case, continuity does **not** follow from the retraction property. E.g. take $X = [0,1] \times \{0,1\}, \, A = [0,1] \times\{0\}$ and $\tau(x,0) = (x,0)$ for $(x,0) \in A$, $\tau(x,1) = (f(x),0)$ for $(x,1) \notin A$, where $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 1):

In topology the word *map* always denotes a *continuous function*. In particular,  the phrase *quotient map* includes continuity.

We get into hot water if we consider non-continuous functions between topological spaces. If we do so, we completely forget the topology of these spaces - it amounts to considering *functions between sets*. In this case  each $A \subset X$ would admit a retraction $r :  X \to A$; simply map all $x \in X \setminus A$ to a fixed $a \in A$.